# Stagg US10 TATTOO strings sound buzzy and loose

Tags: strings, sound, ukulele, buzz

I bought my Stagg US10 TATTOO 1402/117 soprano ukulele yesterday while I was off home. The guy at the shop told me to look up on the internet how to tune it, but because I am bad at it I downloaded a tuenr app on my android phone and tried to tune it like a normal uke should be tuned, GCEA. When I then tried to play the first chrord, C from the song 'Somewhere over the rainbow' I knew something was off. It didn't sound as it should. Then I downloaded 3 more tuning apps and they all say I tuned it correctly. The strange thing is that it doesn't sound nearly as it should. Also, every string except the C one feels like it is loose and maybe because of that it gives me that buzzy sound which I don't like at all. I would really like you help, beacuse I heard some people playing on this uke on youtube and they sounded pretty good, but mine is just oughhhh...

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: can you upload a recording sample?

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you have some of the strings tuned an octave too low?

If you don't know and cannot hear the difference, you need to get a teacher.

Otherwise, your model, at US $35, is an exceptionally cheap ukulele. It may require a setup by a professional guitar technician to make it play correctly, and in this case, a professional adjustment would cost more money than you paid for this extremely cheap instrument.